# Deploy repackaged android (BB10) APP in Blackberry Enterprise Server within workspace

Tags: deployment, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I created the android application using Eclipse Editor. Repacked and signed the application for Blackberry 10 device. I have the signed *.Bar* file. Now i want to release the application. is they allow this type of application to host in **blackberry Enterprise server** with in workspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BB employees have stated at various events I have been to, that the Android runtime is not supported in the Work Perimeter.

And though the following KB article does not say this directly, it does indicate that you will get an error when attempting to add an Android app, and this is by design.

http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=26B86D58FA9ECFA716DD1F2DE34DF4AA?externalId=KB30356&sliceId=2&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl