# Blackberry Server : "Qnx/Android" is not supported

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-jde

I'm converting my Android app (apk) to Blackberry OS 10 (bar).

Everything is ok if i install the bar file to my BB.

But when I try to upload to our BB server to deploy to software to the Z10, i have the problem:

> "Qnx/Android" is not supported

I found the root cause here:

> It is currently not possible to add Android applications to the work
>   perimeter on the BlackBerry Playbook tablet or BlackBerry 10
>   smartphone; this is by design.
>
> Since all applications added to the BlackBerry PlayBook tablet or
>   BlackBerry 10 smartphone via BlackBerry Device Service are installed
>   in the work perimeter, Android applications cannot be installed.
>
> Alternatively, Android applications can be successfully downloaded
>   directly into the personal perimeter on the BlackBerry PlayBook tablet
>   or BlackBerry 10 smartphone.

What's should i do now?
I need to install my app to more hundred of BB10.

Can i reuse my Android code? 
If can't, what's the best solution, best language if i must you write all the code from scratch.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of

[Deploy repackaged android (BB10) APP in Blackberry Enterprise Server within workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490541/deploy-repackaged-android-bb10-app-in-blackberry-enterprise-server-within-work)

You can't reuse any of your code.

The best option depends on the type of application.  If it is reasonably complex, with interaction with on device stuff like location, then Cascades/C++.  Alternatively, you might consider html5.  Have a look round here for more:

https://developer.blackberry.com/

Playbook is another curve ball.  If you have to support that then you can't use Cascades.

And to be honest, there is a certain amount of personal preference involved here too - what do you like writing in?

Just a FYI, it took me about 6 months, part time, to feel fully comfortable with C++/Cascades. This was from nothing, no C, no C++, no experiences of GUI design tools and a different IDE.  But I created my first app, a really simple one, in two weeks.

Comment: Well, this comment is probably offtopic, but given that C++ is probably the most complex of the "modern" programming languages, I'd not feel comfortable with it for years. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/01/the-problem-with-c.html

Comment: Maybe i will use Cascades/C++

Comment: @Mister Smith - :-).  I actually agree, but the Cascades/QT framework isolates you from a lot - for example, it has automatic garbage collection and a proper String class!  So while I am still not comfortable with C++, I am comfortable in writing Cascades/C++.